# Guardar la fecha con DateTimePicker en SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Buen día a todos.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Quiero guardar la fecha que yo seleccione con un `DateTimePicker` en una base de datos de `SQL`que tiene el campo `fecha`de tipo `date` mi codigo del boton guardar es el siguiente:

```
 Private Sub Guardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guardar.Click
    Try
        TestID.Text = Mayor() + 1
        Dim fecha As Date
        Format(fecha, "dd-MM-yyyy")
        fecha = Date.Parse(DateTest.Value.ToShortDateString)
        Dim Conexion As String
        Conexion = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = Conexion
        Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into Debug_Test values(" & TestID.Text & ",'" & TestUser.Text & "','" & SerialNumber.Text & "'," & Shift.Text & ",'" & fecha & "','" & DebugTest.Text & "','" & FailureMode_T.Text & "','" & TestStation_T.Text & "','" & Localidad_T.Text & "','" & SubFamily_T.Text & "','" & Operador_T.Text & "','" & ErrorOperador_T.Text & "','" & Acciones_T.Text & "')", cn)
        cn.Open()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestStation_T.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Localidad_T.Text) Then
            adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(TestStation_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
            adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
            obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

        Else
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Operador_T.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorOperador_T.Text) Then
                adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Operador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(ErrorOperador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
                obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

            Else
                If DebugTest.Text = "4.- Falla Real." Then
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Operador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(ErrorOperador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(TestStation_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Acciones_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
                    obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error de conexion: " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
    TestID.Text = Mayor() + 1
    TestUser.Text = empleado
    SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Shift.Text = Nothing
    DebugTest.Text = Nothing
    TestStation_T.Text = ""
    Localidad_T.Text = ""
    Operador_T.Text = ""
    ErrorOperador_T.Text = ""
    Acciones_T.Text = ""
    TestStation_L.Visible = False
    TestStation_T.Visible = False
    Localidad_L.Visible = False
    Localidad_T.Visible = False
    ComentariosL.Visible = False
    Acciones_L.Visible = False
    Acciones_T.Visible = False
    Operador_L.Visible = False
    Operador_T.Visible = False
    ErrorOperador_L.Visible = False
    ErrorOperador_T.Visible = False
    FailureMode_T.Text = Nothing
    SubFamily_T.Text = Nothing
    Operador_T.Text = Nothing
    TestStation_T.Text = Nothing
    SerialNumber.Focus()

End Sub
```

Cuando selecciono un dia de Diciembre del año 2019, me arroja es el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si selecciono un dia de Enero del año 2020, si me guarda los datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías grabar la fecha con formato YYYYMMDD en la consulta SQL

```
Format(fecha, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Creo que el problema está ahí y probablemente no te dejaba grabar fechas de diciembre porque excedias el año límite que tiene un smalldatetime (2079)

smalldatetime admite desde 01/01/1900 hasta 06/06/2079.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
Private Sub Guardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guardar.Click
    Try
        TestID.Text = Mayor() + 1
        Dim fecha = New Date(DateTest.Value.Year, DateTest.Value.Month, DateTest.Value.Day)
        Dim fe As String
        fe = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim Conexion As String
        Conexion = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = Conexion
        Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into Debug_Test values(" & TestID.Text & ",'" & TestUser.Text & "','" & SerialNumber.Text & "'," & Shift.Text & ",'" & fe & "','" & DebugTest.Text & "','" & FailureMode_T.Text & "','" & TestStation_T.Text & "','" & Localidad_T.Text & "','" & SubFamily_T.Text & "','" & Operador_T.Text & "','" & ErrorOperador_T.Text & "','" & Acciones_T.Text & "')", cn)
        cn.Open()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestStation_T.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Localidad_T.Text) Then
            adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(TestStation_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
            adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
            obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

        Else
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Operador_T.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorOperador_T.Text) Then
                adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Operador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(ErrorOperador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
                obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

            Else
                If DebugTest.Text = "4.- Falla Real." Then
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Operador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(ErrorOperador_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(TestStation_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    adaptador.Parameters.AddWithValue(Acciones_T.Text, DBNull.Value)
                    MsgBox("Se registraron los datos correctamente")
                    obj.LlenarGrilla(DGVFail)

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error de conexion: " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
    TestID.Text = Mayor() + 1
    TestUser.Text = empleado
    SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Shift.Text = Nothing
    DebugTest.Text = Nothing
    TestStation_T.Text = ""
    Localidad_T.Text = ""
    Operador_T.Text = ""
    ErrorOperador_T.Text = ""
    Acciones_T.Text = ""
    TestStation_L.Visible = False
    TestStation_T.Visible = False
    ComentariosL.Visible = False
    Acciones_L.Visible = False
    Acciones_T.Visible = False
    Operador_L.Visible = False
    Operador_T.Visible = False
    ErrorOperador_L.Visible = False
    ErrorOperador_T.Visible = False
    FailureMode_T.Text = Nothing
    SubFamily_T.Text = Nothing
    Operador_T.Text = Nothing
    TestStation_T.Text = Nothing
    SerialNumber.Focus()

End Sub
```

Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que haya funcionado, saludos